# Correct way of installing CyLP in python 3 docker image

Tags: python, docker

I've been trying to install CyLP from python3 docker image, Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

#EXPOSE 42400-42500

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/metis

WORKDIR /usr/src/metis

RUN apt-get update

COPY requirements.txt .


# Install Cbc
RUN wget https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Cbc/Cbc-2.9.9.tgz \
    && tar -xzf Cbc-2.9.9.tgz \
    && cd Cbc-2.9.9 \
    && ./configure --enable-cbc-parallel \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/metis/Cbc-2.9.9.tgz

ENV COIN_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/src/metis/Cbc-2.9.9
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/metis/Cbc-2.9.9/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN pip3 install  -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# Add GCC needed to compile CyLP
# RUN apt-get install python3-dev -y \
#     python-dev \
#     build-essential \
#     manpages-dev

# RUN gcc --version

# # Install CyLP

# COPY CyLP-py3 CyLP-py3

# WORKDIR  /usr/src/metis/CyLP-py3

# RUN COIN_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/src/metis/Cbc-2.9.9 python setup.py install 

WORKDIR /usr/src/metis/

COPY . .


RUN rm -rf /usr/src/metis/cylp-master.tar.gz
CMD [ "python3", "./main.py" ]
```

I even tried downloading and compiling it from source but still getting some errors, the error by trying to install in requirements.txt:

```
pika==1.1.0
numpy==1.17
scipy==1.4.1
cylp==0.9.3
```

Error:

```
Step 9/13 : RUN pip install  -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
 ---> Running in 101f73aa508a
Collecting pika==1.1.0
  Downloading pika-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (148 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.17
  Downloading numpy-1.17.0.zip (6.5 MB)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1
  Downloading scipy-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.0 MB)
Collecting cylp==0.9.3
  Downloading cylp-0.9.3.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-p8n5a_rr/cylp/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-p8n5a_rr/cylp/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-p8n5a_rr/cylp/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-p8n5a_rr/cylp/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-p8n5a_rr/cylp/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import numpy
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Even if numpy is installed before cylp, also been trying with different versions of numpy with no success.

Any hints on how to fix this / why is this happening and how would be the correct way of installing CyLP for python3 ?

Comment: Have you found why this is happening?

Comment: Hey @SMA.D. No i couldnt find why this was happening and just started using the docker image with cylp preinstalled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a docker image with CyLP already installed for Python3:

https://hub.docker.com/r/tkralphs/cylp

Answer (score 0):

I installed CyLP for python 3 using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install unzip git gcc g++ gfortran make wget file pkg-config
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip 
RUN apt-get -y install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
RUN git clone https://github.com/coin-or/coinbrew /var/cbc
WORKDIR /var/cbc
RUN ./coinbrew fetch Cbc:stable/2.10 --no-prompt --no-third-party
RUN ./coinbrew build Cbc --no-prompt --no-third-party --prefix=/usr
ENV COIN_INSTALL_DIR /usr
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install cylp
```

Comment: that is pretty much the Dockerfile of the repo in the answer i posted

Comment: yeah but it is better as its leaner as you don't need to clone the CYLP repo all again.

Comment: This Dockerfile is not optimized. I was searching a "multi-stage build" example.  See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#use-multi-stage-builds